# Expected time complexity of O(n^2), but it results in O(n). Can some explain why?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

What should be the time complexity of the following code?
I tried to think and come up with O(n<sup>2</sup>) but the output says it to be of O(n). Can someone please explain through code?

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(; i < n; i++){
        cout << i << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: @RSahu I think that because the OP says `the output says it to be O(n)` indicates that he has run the code and just wants an explanation of the output

Comment: After the first run of your inner loop, `i==n`, so your outer loop will terminate as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The complexity of your code is O(n).

**Why?**

Because, even though you have written two for loops, which probably made you thinking the complexity is O(n<sup>2</sup>), your code is actually one for loop like:

```cpp
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Once the inner for loop finishes, `i` is equal to `n` and therefore the condition of outer for loop `i < n` is no longer satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

One point to be noted while using such for loops is that your using a single variable.

Irrespective of how many outer loops you add, your code will result in the same with the condition `i<n` prevailing in all. The innermost loop is the one which will run till `i=n-1`, the rest of which simply won't satisfy the condition.

```cpp
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{ for(; i<n; i++)
  { for(; i<n; i++)
    { for(; i<n; i++) // and so on.
       std::cout<<i<<"\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Providing a variant to this, if you were to observe one such case of O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity, your condition would have been `i<n*n`:

```cpp
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{ for(; i<n*n; i++)
    std::cout<<i<<"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Time complexity of your code is `O(n)` and not `O(n^2)` because when inner loop ends, at that time value of i has already reached to n . So outer loop cannot run any more.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    for(; i < 2; i++){
        cout << i << endl;
    }
   //after loop run two times i has value 2.
   //and outer loop cannot run anymore
}
```